# ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from DecorView@2da7146[MyActivity]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-view, android-jetpack-compose

After updating from compose `alpha-11` to `alpha-12`(or `beta-01`) I am getting this crash whenever I open an activity or fragment that has compose views.

I am using `AppCompatActivity` which implements `LifecycleOwner`, so this is extremely odd.

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from DecorView@2da7146[MyActivity]
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:214)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.access$createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:1)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerFactory$Companion$LifecycleAware$1.createRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:98)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerPolicy.createAndInstallWindowRecomposer$ui_release(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:151)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.getWindowRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:199)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.ensureCompositionCreated(ComposeView.android.kt:176)
            at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(ComposeView.android.kt:207)
            at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20014)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3589)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3596)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2223)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1888)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8511)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

My code looks really simple:

```
    class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
            setContent {
                MaterialTheme {
                    Text(text = "compose")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Apparently you need to use `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01`

Comment: Apparently you need to use androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01

Comment: I still have the same issue with `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. Updating to version 1.3.0-beta01 didn't help. Do you know where the problem lies?

Comment: @Ibasek Probably related with this bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180691023

Comment: @ClapaLucian solution worked for me. Essentialy adding `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0-SNAPSHOT"` to your module `build.gradle` and add `maven { url 'https://androidx.dev/snapshots/builds/7166224/artifacts/repository' }` to the list of repositories

Answer (score 18):

Try updating the dependency of `AppCompat` to `rc01` version.
This solved the problem for me.

`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-rc01'`

Answer (score 5):

If your view is something old, in my case it was Dialog,
you can try add such lines to set view tree owner manually

```
val decorView: View = dialog?.window?.decorView ?: throw IllegalStateException("Failed to get decorview")
        ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(decorView, this)
        ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(decorView, this)
        view.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(decorView.findViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner())
```

In such way DialogFragment was fixed here:

https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1610494/1/fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment.java#48

Comment: I have same problem with Dialog. Where should I add these lines to fix it?

Comment: In Google's code they added it after  dialog.show() in onStart 
 // Only after we show does the dialog window actually return a decor view.

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` from `1.2.0` to `1.3.1` solved the issue for me.

**TLDR:**
Update

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0"
```

to

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1"
```

Answer (score 3):

As none of the solutions worked for me, I'm here to make your day easier (assuming you have the configuration that I had for my project).

So, here was the activity that didn't launch after upgrading to `beta01`:

```
class AuthenticationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, SignInFragment())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is not `setContentView(...)` in here. After analyzing the stacktrace I saw that `setTag(R.id.view_tree_lifecycle_owner, lifecycleOwner)` wasn't getting performed which resulted in `getTag()` to return null - hence exception.

Turns out `setTag(...)` is getting called when any of `setContentView()` overloads is performed.

So, the easy fix for my setup was to introduce a redundant `setContentView(View(this))` which internally would set the lifecycle owner:

```
class AuthenticationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(View(this)) // <-- here's the newly introduced line
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, SignInFragment())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered same issue with `BottomSheetDialogFragment`
You have to upgrade `fragment` to [`1.3.1`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.1)

Thanks to @clapa-lucian, you can find more about in this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180691023)

Answer (score 3):

Switching from `AppCompatActivity` to `FragmentActivity` solved this issue in my case.

Comment: This worked for me after trying many many many different suggestions. I wish I could give you more Up arrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was because I had not included the *appcompat* library and my activity inherited from *Activity* instead of *AppCompatActivity*. The problem resolved by adding the library:

```kotlin
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0")
```

and subclassing from *AppCompatActivity*:

```kotlin
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. Others suggested to upgrade but I didn't have the dependency at all in my project.

Answer (score 0):

@Penzzz's suggestion works! One thing to note is you do have to provide implementations for `LifecycleOwner`, `SavedStateRegistryOwner`, and `ViewModelStoreOwner`. These are fairly easy.

I did run into the following error though:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can consumeRestoredStateForKey only after super.onCreate of corresponding component
```

This is fixed by calling savedRegistryOwner.restore(savedInstanceState) in `onCreate()` function, alongside corresponding calls in `onSavedInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  savedRegistryOwnerImpl.restore(savedInstanceState)
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  lifeCycleOwnerImpl.onCreate()
}
```

I found this out by looking into how `ComponentActivity` uses `SavedStateRegistry`.