# Jetpack Compose - Problem with BottomSheetDialogFragment and ViewTreeLifecycleOwner

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

After updating the Jetpack Compose library to `beta01`, I'm not able to show DialogFragment or BottomSheetDialogFragment.
Looks like `ViewTreeLifecycleOwner` cannot be found in my activity anymore. Also, I tried a couple of possible [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66382502/viewtreelifecycleowner-not-found-from-decorview2da7146myactivity) but there are not any success.

The view in fragment is inflated with:

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_full_screen_layout, container, false
        ).apply {
            findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view).setContent {...}
```

and dialog fragment is showing with:

```
DialogFragmentExample.newInstance().show(supportFragmentManager, null)
```

Does anyone have a similar problem? Please, any suggestion would be welcome.

Stacktracke:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from DecorView@409dd5d[MainActivity]
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:214)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.access$createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:1)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerFactory$Companion$LifecycleAware$1.createRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerPolicy.createAndInstallWindowRecomposer$ui_release(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:151)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.getWindowRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:199)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.ensureCompositionCreated(ComposeView.android.kt:177)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(ComposeView.android.kt:222)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Fragment 1.3.1 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.1):

> Dialogs within a `DialogFragment` can now get access to ViewTree owners through their DecorView, ensuring that `DialogFragment` can be used with `ComposeView`. ([Ib9290](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/q/Ib92905306e16dcaee63c985f22b5e36b6718dd39), [b/180691023](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180691023))

So you should make sure you upgrade to Fragment 1.3.1:

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.1"
```

Comment: I tried with snapshot build and that wasn't successful, but this works! You save my day, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I get the same exception without even using a `DialogFragment`.

My workaround is to set the `ViewTreeLifecycleOwner` from the `Activity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

      ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(window.decorView, this)
      // setContent(...); add fragment using Compose view
   }
}
```

I'm currently using the following libraries:

- `androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.0-alpha04`
- `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.1`
- `androidx.compose.*:*:1.0.0-beta02`

Comment: this one worked for me too even with Compose runtime beta03, I was not using dialog fragment either, but the bottom navigation view with fragments