# java.lang.IllegalStateException :ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from DecorView@5ab7e30[MainActivity]

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack, illegalstateexception, android-jetpack-compose

i followed [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop#compose-in-views) documentation for  including a **ComposeView** directly inside a fragment **without xml layout inflating** , but it giving **java.lang.IllegalStateException**.

please help me to fix this issue.

Android Studio: 2020.3.1 canary 14

compose_version :'1.0.0-beta01'

this is Fragment's code:

```
class RecipeListFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var viewModel: RecipeListViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        setContent {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Recipe List",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3
                )
            }
        }
    }

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(RecipeListViewModel::class.java)
}
```

}

this is run time error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mvvmrecepiapp, PID: 18722
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from DecorView@5ab7e30[MainActivity]
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:214)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.access$createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:1)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerFactory$Companion$LifecycleAware$1.createRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:97)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerPolicy.createAndInstallWindowRecomposer$ui_release(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:152)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.getWindowRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:200)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.ensureCompositionCreated(ComposeView.android.kt:200)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(ComposeView.android.kt:235)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:19553)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2028)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

**UPDATE:**

here is my build.gradle(:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mvvmrecepiapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.4.32'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'

//    compose_version = "1.0.0-beta01" variable in project level build.gradle
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"


    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha06'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'

    def fragment_version = "1.3.2"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"

    def nav_version = "2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"


     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
     androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.0-beta04"

}
```

Comment: @khanumer Try the appcompat:1.3.0-beta01

Comment: awesome @GabrieleMariotti  Thank you it's working fine with appcompat:1.3.0-cr01 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from DecorView@2da7146\[MyActivity\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66382502/viewtreelifecycleowner-not-found-from-decorview2da7146myactivity)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The support for `ViewTreeLifecycleOwner` was introduced in the AppCompat with the version 1.3.0.

Currently the latest AppCompat release is

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
```

Comment: similar problem with appcompat 1.4.2. any suggestions?

Comment: I have been fighting with this for 2 days. THANK YOU!