# Jetpack Compose : ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm getting this error while using Compose in my fragment which works fine in case of XML

`ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`

I'm using a single activity approach **without** using Jetpack Navigation component

*Activity*:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav)
  supportFragmentManager.commit {
    setReorderingAllowed(true)
    add<InboxFragment>(R.id.nav_fragmentContainerView_appNav)
  }
}
```

```xml
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/nav_fragmentContainerView_appNav"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

*Fragment*:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
  return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
    setContent {
      Text(text = "HELLO FRIEND!")
    }
  }
}
```

*Dependencies*:

```
def fragment_version = "1.3.3"
implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version")

def compose_version = "1.0.0-beta06"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha07"
```

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha15"
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30"
```

Comment: Are you using an AppCompatActivity?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yeah `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`

Comment: The support for `ViewTreeLifecycleOwner` was introduced in the AppCompat with the version `1.3.0`. Use: `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-rc01'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from DecorView@2da7146\[MyActivity\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66382502/viewtreelifecycleowner-not-found-from-decorview2da7146myactivity)

Comment: I suggest that you remove "Jetpack Comppose" from the title and tags, as this issue is unrelated to Compose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are using an `AppCompatActivity`, only the appcompat `1.3` versions populate the `ViewTreeLifecycleOwner`.

Add:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
```

Comment: same issue on appcompat 1.4.2. any suggestions?

Comment: Check if you use appropriare activity. If you use ComponentActivity it should be from import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity

Answer (score 7):

It's just a simple name change, from class with static method to extension methods:

`ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.get(view)` changed to `View.findViewTreeLifecycleOwner()`
`ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set()` to `View.setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner?)`

Answer (score 3):

None of these worked and there seems to be an open issue with BottomSheetDialog.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/261078350

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I encountered this error when using coil with 2.3.0 Changing the coil version to 2.2.2 solved the problem.

Comment: They just changed the way you set it.
ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(view, owner) -> view.setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(owner)