# Jetpack Compose inside Fragment ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout, androidx, android-jetpack-compose

I'm getting `IllegalStateException` error while using Compose in my fragment.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from
> androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

The activity is AppCompatActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

I'm using `Navigation Component` to navigate between fragments. and this is Activities XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/appContent"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And Fragment:

```
class WelcomeFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(
                DisposeOnLifecycleDestroyed(viewLifecycleOwner)
            )

            setContent {
                MaterialTheme {
                    Text(text = "Welcome to App")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dependencies and versions:

```
FragmentVersion = '1.3.3'
CONSTRAINT_LAYOUT_VERSION = '2.1.0'
KOTLIN_VERSION = '1.5.21'
ACTIVITY_KTX_VERSION = '1.3.1'

COMPOSE_VERSION = '1.0.0'
COMPOSE_ACTIVITY = '1.3.1'
COMPOSE_VIEWMODEL = '1.0.0-alpha07'
COMPOSE_CONSTRAINT_VERSION = '1.0.0-beta02'
APP_COMPAT_VERSION = '1.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by switching from AppCompatActivity to FragmentAcivity!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful for others but I actually found the issue was that I had an older version of the AppCompatActivity library in my `app/build.gradle`, you should update it to at least 1.3.0 or higher
Similar to what this answer suggests:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67586890/14158634